# Conditional expectation on an event

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf (probability density function) $f$. Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. How to compute $E(X|X\in A)$? This is a condition expectation that conditions on an event instead of another random variable $Y$. I don't see such a topic covered in any book, because $X$ is always a discrete random variable when a book talks about conditioning on an event. And when $X$ is continuous, the conditional expectation is always about another random variable $Y$.

I have the following argument $$E(X|X\in A)=\int x f(x|A)\,dx,$$ where $f(x|A)$ is the conditional density function, which conditions on an event $A$. I don't find a definition of it in any probability book so here is my definition $$f(x|A)=\frac{f(x)1_A(x)}{P(A)}.$$
With this definition, we have
$$
E(X|X\in A)=\int x f(x|A)\,dx=\int_{x\in A} \frac{xf(x)}{P(A)}\,dx=\frac{\int_{x\in A} xf(x)\,dx}{\int_{x\in A} f(x)\,dx}.
$$

For example, $E(X|X\le 5)=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^5 xf(x)\,dx}{\int_{-\infty}^5 f(x)\,dx}$.

Does my argument above correct? Is there a way to fit the above theory into a general theory given in a standard probability book? For example, does it have something to do with $E(X|Y)$ where $Y$ is another random variable? Any book covering such a problem is also welcomed.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $P(A)=\int_{x\in A} f(x)\,dx >0$. This is an important assumption.  If so,  $f(x\mid A)=\frac{f(x)}{P(A)}$ for $x \in A$ and  $E(X\mid X\in A)=\frac{\int_{x\in A} xf(x)\,dx}{\int_{x\in A} f(x)\,dx}$  are indeed correct.

Comment: "I don't see such a topic covered in any book," 
Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditioning_on_an_event
Anyway, consider the random variable $Y=1_A(X)$. Then $E(X|A) =E(X|Y=1)$

Comment: @leonbloy Setting $Y$ to be the indicator function is indeed a clever treatment. But how to compute the joint distribution f(x,y)? In fact, this is case X is continuous but Y is discrete. Does any book cover such a topic?

Comment: @leonbloy Wikipedia does not cover the case when X is continuous and A is an event. It only covers the case X is discrete.

Comment: Your argument is correct. In fact, the conditional expectation of a r.v. $X$ given an event $A$ is defined as $$\mathbb E[X\mid A] = \frac1{\mathbb P(A)}\int_A X\ \mathsf d\mathbb P = \frac{\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_A]}{\mathbb P(A)}$$
in some texts. This definition can be found on "Basic Stochastic Processes" by  Zdzislaw Brzezniak, Tomasz Zastawniak and "Probability and Stochastics" by Erhan Çınlar, for instance.